# How to use not equal query in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, phpmyadmin, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

[image]

> I have two tables ad_pool and advertisment. ad_pool has some data while advertisment is empty. I am using this code to select values from the first table by not equal query like this andWhere(['<>','fisttablekey','second_tbl_key']). This is the complete code i am using to retrieve the data and i also uploaded the image.

```
$pool1 = (new Query())>select('p.id,p.cleaner_user_id,p.ad_place_id')
                   ->from('ad_pool p')
                   ->innerJoin('advertisment a' , 'p.id = a.pool_id')
                 ->where(['=','ad_place_id',1])
                 ->andWhere(['<>','p.id','a.pool_id'])
                 ->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))
                // ->limit(1)
                ->all();
                  var_dump($pool1);
                  exit();
```

this return me Empty array. need your kind help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `all()` with `createCommand()->rawSql` and run the output of it in your DB console to see if you get any results.

Comment: it gave me this error... syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.
Since your advertisement is empty, it won't return any data. You can use LEFT JOIN instead.

```
$pool1 = (new Query())>select('p.id,p.cleaner_user_id,p.ad_place_id')
                   ->from('ad_pool p')
                   ->leftJoin('advertisment a' , 'p.id = a.pool_id')
                 ->where(['=','ad_place_id',1])
                 ->andWhere(['<>','p.id','a.pool_id'])
                 ->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))
                ->all();
```

[W3Schools Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: Have you tried it using active record? Include a method getAdvertisements()

Comment: yes that's the problem. I want retrieve data from first table but need to check if its id already exists then ignore that one. how can i do this? could you suggest me any solution for this

Comment: $pool1 = (new Query())->select('ad_pool.id,ad_pool.cleaner_user_id,ad_pool.ad_place_id')
                       ->from('ad_pool')
                    ->leftJoin('advertisment a' , 'ad_pool.id = a.pool_id')
                     ->where(['=','ad_place_id',1])
                     ->andWhere(['!=','ad_pool.id','a.pool_id'])
                     ->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))
                 // ->limit(1)
              ->one();
                  return $pool1;
                  exit();    its working but still there is problem is not equal->andWhere(['!=','ad_pool.id','a.pool_id'])

Answer (score 0):

[image: This way i solved this problem after whole day search]

This way I solved this problem after 3 to 4 hours hardwork. Get the required values from the second table if there is any and then convert it into single array and used it in the NOT IN condition. (we must have passion of helping others and we should help each other).